# How to display JSON having HTML data?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, json

I have HTML tags and entities in JSON, I don't know how to display it in my app. I tried removing new lines, I tried decoding html entities but nothing worked.

Below is an example of JSON I have:

```
{"Jobdesc":[{"jobid":"12281","job_title":"IOS Developer for Noida Location Job","job_desc":"&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Job Description&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;

Dear Candidate&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

I have an opening for IOS Developer for Noida Location for leading IT company. pli\ease find the JD below-&lt;br /&gt;

JOB DESCRIPTION :-&lt;br /&gt;

Industry :- IT&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Experience :- Min 1 Year&lt;br /&gt;

Position :- IOS Developer&lt;br /&gt;

Location :- Noida&lt;br /&gt;

&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

&lt;strong&gt;Job Responsibility :-&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br /&gt;

&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Design and build advanced applications for the iOS platform&lt;br /&gt;

Collaborate with cross-functional teams to define, design, and ship new features&lt;/p&gt;



&lt;p&gt;Working experience in iOS development&lt;br /&gt;

Have published one or more iOS apps in the app store&lt;br /&gt;

A deep familiarity with Objective-C and Cocoa Touch&lt;br /&gt;

Experience working with iOS frameworks such as Core Data, Core      Animation, Core Graphics and Core Text&lt;br /&gt;

&amp;nbsp;If you are interested in the above mentioned JD kindly share your resume with me and contact me on :-&lt;br /&gt;

 &amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

 Thanks And Regards&lt;br /&gt;

 Pal Mittal&lt;br /&gt;

 Contact no :- 9200272001&lt;br /&gt;

 Email ID :- parul@india-shine.in&lt;br /&gt;

&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Functional Area: Web / Mobile Technologies&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Industry: IT - Software&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Skills: IOS ipad&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Other Skills: IOS Developer Iphone Developer IOS Application Developer    iphone Application Developer iphone&lt;br /&gt;

&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Recruiter details&amp;nbsp;&lt;br /&gt;

Company Name:  Employment Solution&lt;br /&gt;

Email: pal@ishine.in&lt;br /&gt;

Telephone: 9200272001&lt;/p&gt;

","job_role":"IOS Developer","job_exp":"1-4  year","job_education":"MCA","job_location":"Delhi","job_address":"Delhi","j  ob_company_name":"India Shine Employment  Solution","job_company_url":"www.india- shine.in","job_company_email":"kumar178dilip@gmail.com","job_status":""}]}
```

Comment: actually not possible with the above json because, no parser would be able to parse this.. for instance `br /` how would any parser recognize that its a break tag

Comment: @Sharpkits Yeah ! i have too many JSON response like this,thought somehow i managed many of them, through coding and decoding html entities , what should be done now ? can i use exception handling in this?

Comment: Can you please provide more details regarding how much you were able to parse? and what is the output display you wish to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there are 2 approaches

***Approach 1***

**Code**

```
@interface NSAttributedString (HTML)
+ (instancetype)attributedStringWithHTMLString:(NSString *)htmlString;
@end

@implementation NSAttributedString (HTML)
+ (instancetype)attributedStringWithHTMLString:(NSString *)htmlString
{
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                               NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute :@(NSUTF8StringEncoding) };

    NSData *data = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
}

@end
```

**Usage**

```
NSString *cleanString = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithHTMLString:question.title] string];
```

***Approach 2***

Check out [NSString category for XMLEntities](http://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString+XMLEntities.m). There's methods to decode XML entities (including all HTML character references), encode XML entities, stripping tags and removing newlines and whitespace from a string:

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingTags;
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingXMLEntities; // Including all HTML character references
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingXMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringWithNewLinesAsBRs;
- (NSString *)stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWebView and show it like this:

```
let htmlString = //HTML String      
webView.delegate = self
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
webView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```